# How to change the datagrid back ground color

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

Using .Net 2005

i change the background row color in default cell style (white to blue). But blue is displaying not all the rows.

Alternative row is appearing as white.  I want to display all the rows as a same color.

Can any one help me to do.

Comment: :please share your code.

Comment: See AlternatingRowStyle if you changed only RowStyle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi you can set gridview row background color  like this

```
protected void gridview _RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
      if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
      {  e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have set AlternatingRowStyle property in gridview in aspx. If yes, remove it and only set RowStyle property. e.g-

```
<RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
```