# How to apply both cell color and alternating row color in aspx gridview at a time

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I am using aspxgridview of devexpress. I have applied different cellstyle-colors on cells. and now i want to make alternate row of grid as shaded(light of same color). I am applying alternating color, but even it is not applied when cellstyle-color is set. Any one has an idea regarding this please. thanks in advance.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13487354/how-to-change-the-datagrid-back-ground-color/13487550#13487550

Comment: Nag this is about simple gridview. I have an aspx gridview of dev express.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Anton, but i have done it with javascript. I am using even and odd propery of table like following. here is function which i am calling in document.ready function. and also calling on each button's click event from server side.

function colorGrid() {

```
        /*code for color coding grid*/
        $(".student_account td table tbody tr'[id]':odd").addClass('initial');
        $(".student_account td table tbody tr'[id]':even").addClass('initial');

        /* For odd Rows */

        // for first 3 columns
        $(".student_account td table tbody tr'[id]':odd  td:nth-child(1)").css("background-color", "#EEEEEE");
        $(".student_account td table tbody tr'[id]':odd  td:nth-child(2)").css("background-color", "#EEEEEE");
        $(".student_account td table tbody tr'[id]':odd  td:nth-child(3)").css("background-color", "#EEEEEE");

        // for 4th and 5th column
        $(".student_account td table tbody tr'[id]':odd  td:nth-child(4)").css("background-color", "#EBFAE3");
        $(".student_account td table tbody tr'[id]':odd  td:nth-child(5)").css("background-color", "#EBFAE3");


        // for 6th t0 9th column
        $(".student_account td table tbody tr'[id]':odd  td:nth-child(6)").css("background-color", "#F7F8D6");
        $(".student_account td table tbody tr'[id]':odd  td:nth-child(7)").css("background-color", "#F7F8D6");
        $(".student_account td table tbody tr'[id]':odd  td:nth-child(8)").css("background-color", "#F7F8D6");
        $(".student_account td table tbody tr'[id]':odd  td:nth-child(9)").css("background-color", "#F7F8D6");


        // for 10th column
        $(".student_account td table tbody tr'[id]':odd  td:nth-child(10)").css("background-color", "#CBE6F7");



        /* For Even Rows */

        var name = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdScheduleStudent_DXHeadersRow";

        // for first 3 columns
        $(".student_account td table tbody tr'[id]':even  td:nth-child(1)").css("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
        $(".student_account td table tbody tr'[id]':even  td:nth-child(2)").css("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
        $(".student_account td table tbody tr'[id]':even  td:nth-child(3)").css("background-color", "#FFFFFF");

        // for 4th and 5th column
        $(".student_account td table tbody tr'[id]':even  td:nth-child(4)").css("background-color", "#F5FAF3");
        $(".student_account td table tbody tr'[id]':even  td:nth-child(5)").css("background-color", "#F5FAF3");


        // for 6th t0 9th column
        $(".student_account td table tbody tr'[id]':even  td:nth-child(6)").css("background-color", "#FBFCEA");
        $(".student_account td table tbody tr'[id]':even  td:nth-child(7)").css("background-color", "#FBFCEA");
        $(".student_account td table tbody tr'[id]':even  td:nth-child(8)").css("background-color", "#FBFCEA");
        $(".student_account td table tbody tr'[id]':even  td:nth-child(9)").css("background-color", "#FBFCEA");


        // for 10th column
        $(".student_account td table tbody tr'[id]':even  td:nth-child(10)").css("background-color", "#EDF8FE");

        $(".student_account td table tbody tr'[id=" + name + "]' td").css("background-color", "#56A52E");

        /*end color coding*/
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use DevExpress css styles (instead of setting up properties of ASPxGridView) like this:

```
.dxgvDataRow:hover
 {
   color: gray;
 }
```

You can also use CssPostfix property of an ASPxGridView to set different styles for the control. For example:

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="grid" runat="server"  Styles-CssPostfix="MyGrid" ...
```

would use following css:

```
.dxgvDataRow_MyGrid:hover
 {
   color: gray;
 }
```

To observe ASPx css class names just open a browser in development mode and look through the source code, you can find such classes: dxgvDataRowHover, dxgvFocusedRow, dxgvSelectedRow and many others.

The advantage of such style customization is that html markup doesn't create style attribute for each of an html element, css editing is easier and faster and there's no need to customize every ASPxGridView control by setting up its properties.